# PHP Laravel form submission issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the users registered on a single form.
In that form the user enters his work experience and the fields in that are shown in drop down select html element. For Example company name , from year , to year.

Now i have given add experience button on this section so that it gets added into the table and the table is shown dynamically whenever the user clicks on add experience.

In laravel i could not get the data added into the table and hence i chose to submit the form through java script where i get the table data , convert it into array and pass a single json string a request body to the api then extract the data into laravel controller and store into database.

In many forums, others have answered to add hidden elements and get the data, but i did not find it reliable.

So my question here is , is there any way i can first process the request the into java script , modify its request body and usually execute the api, just like any other simple laravel php api or is there any simpler way to do this ?

Sharing code snippets from my code ,

**html page snippet**

```
 <form name="RegistrationForm" id="RegistrationForm">

                                    <label for="from_year" class="col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('From Year') }}</label>
                                    <select id="from_year" class="form-control" name="from_year"  value="{{ old('from_year') }}" required>

                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                        <option value="2011">2011</option>

                                    </select>
                                    
                                    
                                    <label for="to_year" class="col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('To Year') }}</label>
                                    <select id="to_year" class="form-control" name="to_year"  value="{{ old('to_year') }}" required>

                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                        <option value="2011">2011</option>

                                    </select>
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" id="BtnSubmitForm"  name="BtnSubmitForm" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            {{ __('Submit') }}
                                    </button>
```

**javascript code**

```
 $('#RegistrationForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var mainObj = {};
    
    var total_exp_months = $('#to_year').val();
    var currently_employed = $('#from_year').val();
     
    $("#RegistrationForm").validate({

        rules: {

            to_year: "required",
            from_year: "required"

        },

        messages: {

            to_year: "Please Select option",
            from_year: "Please Select option"
         

        },

    }); 
    
    // Here i get data from table which was added in the form and convert it into json String to pass to the api
    
  $.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: '/register_user',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestStringObj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data, status) {

        // success message

    },
    error: function(data, status) {

       // error message

    }
  });
```

});

This is the sample image how the data is being added into table dynamically.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it will be helpful if show us what you have done. Please produce an example in code of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine please find the edit in the question.

Comment: @xNoJustice : Hey hi, just like mentioned i do not want to use multiple pages for the form. My objective is different.

Comment: where is this requestStringObj coming from? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: what request are you hoping to process with javascript?

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine : Hey , Thanks for the quick replies on my issue.
requestStringObj is being created after validation process.
I am trying to just make it simple in Laravel what i am doing currently in java script.

Comment: _In laravel i could not get the data added into the table and hence_ -- What do you mean by that? What are you actually trying to achieve here? Someone can help you if you narrow this down to a 1 sentence question / idea of the objective.

Comment: Are you just trying to submit a form to a Laravel api endpoint and store the data?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane please have a look at the question. i have added an image.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane yes i am trying to submit data to laravel endpoint. What happens here is i cannot extract the data added into the table from php form, hence i have to use javascript to fetch the data from table element and provide it to laravel end point api. My question is there any other way where javascript part can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using ajax to submit the form, So you need to pass the CSRF token in your ajax submit. Remember by default CSRF is enabled in laravel. Your ajax should be like below:

```
$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: '/register_user',
data: JSON.stringify(requestStringObj),
headers: {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data, status) {

    // success message

},
error: function(data, status) {

   // error message

}
```

});

And include CSRF token into the meta tag of your header in html.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I hope it will work.